# Annotation processor 'com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAp' not found

Tags: ant, weblogic

I have a Java app I inherited that is running on a Weblogic 12.2.1 server. It is using JDK 1.8.0_172.

When I try to build it using an ANT build.xml file, I get the following error:

```
Annotation processor 'com.sun.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAp' not found
```

And the error points to this line in the build.xml file...

```
<jwsc srcdir="${src}" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${ear.dir}" verbose="off" debug="on" classpathref="compile.class.path" >
```

I've tried reverting my Weblogic to 12.1 and several other things - nothing has worked so far.

And I'm having trouble knowing what to fix because I can't find a reference to a WebServiceAp anywhere in the project or workspace.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the library ${MW_HOME}/oracle_common/modules/clients/com.oracle.webservices.fmw.client.jar to your classpath before running your ant tasks.

Comment: Thanks.  Is that a jar file that I would find within my installation of Oracle?  I have both Oracle 12.1.3.0 and 12.2.1.3 installed and I've scoured both for any instance of a com.oracle.webservices.fmw.client.jar.  I don't think it exists in either installation.

Comment: You should find it in 12.2.1.3